# Doubt from Allen Hatcher's AT about CW Complex

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am trying to learn Cellular Homology from Allen Hatcher's AT book, but stuck in first Lemma (2.34) itself. While introducing Cellular Homology Hatcher in his AT, Section 2.2 Lemma 2.34 says $X^n/X^{n-1}$  is a wedge sum of $n$ - spheres, one for each $n$- cell of $X$. Where $X$ is a $CW$ Complex.

I am unable to prove this, couldn't even think a bit how to start or where to start.
Please guide me.

Comment: It sounds like you're learning from Allen Hatcher's book, not the person himself.  Regarding your question, you build $X^n$ from $X^{n-1}$ by attaching $n$-dimensional discs along maps of their boundary spheres.  So if you crush $X^{n-1}$, you are crushing not only all the boundary spheres to one common point, but everything else in the space too.

Comment: @RyanBudney, sorry for my English, thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each $n$-cell of $X$ is a ball glued along its boundary to the $(n-1)$-skeleton. If you collapse the $(n-1)$-skeleton to a point, you're collapsing the boundary of each $n$-cell to a point and identifying all those points. A ball whose boundary is collapsed to a point is a sphere, so $X^n/X^{n-1}$ is a sphere for each $n$-cell, all glued along the point to which the $(n-1)$-skeleton was collapsed.

Comment: Neal, thanks for your answer, your answer gave me better understanding of CW Complexes.